# To bind Usercontrol in aspx using ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

In the below code I have a usercontrol Control.ascx I have a textbox and dropdown and I want to check with db whether field is textbox or dropdown and I want to display in sample.aspx using ajax. Pls help me to do this.

**Control.ascx**

```
<table width="100%">
<tr>
      <td>
         <input type="text"  id="btnField" value="Val" />
      </td>
      <td>
         <select id="cbB" style="width:75%"></select>
      </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**sample.aspx**

```
  <table>
       <tr>
           <td>
               <uc1:UcReport ID="ucReport" runat="server" />
           </td>
       </tr>        
    </table>        

     function LoadUserControl() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Sample.aspx/LoadControls",
                data: "",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r) {

                    var data = $.parseJSON(r.d);
                    alert(r.d);  
                }
            });        
        }

         //will return textbox or dropdown
         [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
         public static string LoadControls()
         {
              string Test= "2";

              Client Controls = new Client();
              DataSet dsField = Controls.GetFieldData(Int32.Parse(Test));
              string sReturn = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dsField.Tables[0]).ToString();
              return sReturn;     
         }
```

Comment: where are you stuck?

Comment: @Amit Kumar Ghosh I don't know how to bind usercontrol  in aspx page as i am new to asp.net

Comment: see this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667423/Load-UserControl-using-jQuery

Comment: @Amit Kumar Ghosh i tried it didn't work

Comment: @Amit Kumar Ghosh thanks it works